# Next js и mongoose-mongoDB подключение

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nextjs

Всем привет несколько дней пытаюсь подключить базу данных к своему проекту, делаю уже в тупую по видосу
Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста
Подключаю mongoose и mongoDB Compass(на компьютере установлен и запущен(оттуда же и данные для подключения)

есть файл .env в котором
`MONGO_URI="mongodb://localhost:27017/user"` (пробовал и создавать базу и писать имя от несуществующей

В папке utils создал файл connectToMongo.js

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const connectDB = async () => mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);

export default connectDB;
```

Дальше папка models c файлом users.js

```
import { Schema, model, models } from "mongoose";

const testSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String, 
        required: true, 
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String, 
        required: true
    },
    email:{
        type: String, 
        unique: true
    }
})
const Test = models.Test || model("Test", testSchema);

export default Test;
```

И в папке api/test/add.js

```
import connectDB from "@/utils/connectToMongo";
import Test from "@/models/users";


/**
 * @param {import("next").NextApiRequest} req 
 * @param {import("next").NextApiResponse} res 
 */

export default async function handler(req, res){
    const {username, password, email} = req.body;
    console.log("Try to connect to db");
    await connectDB()
    console.log("DB is connected");
    
    console.log("Creating document");
    const test  = await Test.create(req.body);
    console.log("Created document");

    res.json({ test });
}
```

Запускаю проект
И в thunder client делаю post
http://localhost:3000/api/test/add
Где body

```
{
"username": "Test_1",
"password": "123test",
"email": "ds@mail.ru"
}
```

Сколько вариантов не пробовал всегда идет 404
Заранее сори, если вопрос глупый, но сам изучаю и ничего не выходит

Comment: А папка `api` находится в `pages`?

Comment: Нет, она лежит в `app`

Comment: а pages в основную директорию надо или в app?

Comment: какая версия nextjs используется?